# Removing entry details text in email in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to remove entry details text from sent emails? And if yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can configure your email notifications or email confirmations to not include the entry details. This can be configured in the submission setting of your form.

There is an option to not include entry details under both the "Receive email notification?" section and the "Send email confirmations?" section.

> **Include entry details** – Check this box to include the form entry data in the notification email. Please note that if your form is capturing sensitive data, we do not recommend this option.

For more information on this setting and other submission settings, please see the help topic [Understanding submission settings](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/20/building-forms/notification-emails#include)
on our support site.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).